# Does DataWeave keeps the order of JSON properties?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I cannot see in the DataWeave documentation if it keeps the order of the properties. For example after this code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    giftcards :  payload  map  {
        "currency" : $.currency,
        "giftcardId" : $."_id",
        "amount" : $.price
    }
}
```

Can we expect that we will get the following sequence of properties in the response:

1. currency
2. giftcardId
3. amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is "Yes" but general answer is "No".
Even Mule should produce JSON exact as defined in DateWeave it does not mean that other transformations will not destroy this order. Simple transformation to Map and back will change it base on particular Map implementation. It could be Hashtable or ordered collection to keep key/value pairs and so order will be naturally broken.

Bottom line - since you do not know what transformations data will have - do not rely on the order in the original or some middle stage order. Always control it by yourself. For example - order key alphabetically when extract from the collection.

Comment: I presume that you are right. This is the answer I got from Mule themselves: "The order defined in the body will most probably will respected for XML and json
In Java the map are unordered." So, I presume your answer is closest to reality. It is not 100% guaranteed I think.

Answer (score 0):

It will retain the sequence of your data. because all declaration under dataweave goes under output directives. The Output Directive specifies what the output type is in a transformation, which is specified using content/type. Only one output can be specified, the structure of this output is then defined in the DataWeave body.

Comment: Thank  you for your reply! However, Mule didnt give me exactly that answer (please check my comment on the previous reply). The answer from Mule leaves me with a room for doubt though.